# FSharp type provider with Azure SQL Server / Azure Active Directory

Tags: f#, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, type-providers

We have an FSharp project using a SQL type provider, which means that during the build, we need access to the target SQL Server DB. For debug builds, that's our own local machines, where we can use integrated security, but our test and production builds point to Azure SQL databases. Up until recently, we've been following the Definitely Not Best Practice of storing in source the password for the SQL Server account the type provider uses, to make compiling simpler.

We need to move away from that, as it's a pretty obvious and nasty security risk.

The problem is what to replace it with. Azure SQL doesn't support "Integrated Security", so we can't do something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OurDatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ourserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=OurDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The other way of doing it involves Azure Active Directory. But if you use the "Active Directory with Password" approach, you're still storing the password in the source (or at least, in a file somewhere).

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OurDatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ourserver.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Password; Initial Catalog=OurDatabase; UID=bob@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; PWD=MyPassWord!" />
</connectionStrings>
```

That's maybe workable, if everyone is doing deploys from their own machines: you could have folks copy a file with their AD password in plaintext into the appropriate directory. That's not great, but maybe OK? But we use a shared machine for deploys, which makes this solution not great.

You can also use an AD token, but that requires that the application specifically be coded in such a way as to know about Azure AD, and so far as I'm aware, that's not the case with FSharp type providers. Or at least, Googling has turned up anything.

What do other folks do in this scenario?

Comment: What build system are you using? Can it do a regex search-and-replace (or a simple string search-and-replace) step before calling the F# compiler? If so, you could put the string "\_\_DB_PASSWORD\_\_" in your source, and have the build system replace it with "4ctu4lP4$$w0rd" right before the compile step.

Comment: @rmunn - I think that mostly has the same problems as just copying over a .config file with the appropriate password in it. It would work, sort of, on a local dev machine, though I don't like the idea of critical passwords floating about in plaintext. But we use a shared deployment box, with multiple folks using the same folder to deploy from, so it sort of defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: You could combine that with [BlackBox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox) (by Stack Exchange, incidentally) to keep your secrets encrypted, and only have them decrypted during the build process. I haven't used it in production because my other team members don't see a value in moving away from what works for us (secrets stored in TeamCity build variables), but in my private testing I've found it to be quite useful.